# Profiler Program for MySQL like in MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, profiler

is there a Profiler like in T-SQL namely SQL Server to trace queries for MYSQL.

I am using Windows, XAMPP MySQL. I have this PHP Command that is so simple yet it does not update properly. I want to see if it is being run properly so I would like to trace it like in MSSQL.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has an inbuild profiler, which allows you to see very detailed for what part of the query how much time has been spend.

To enable it, use this statement:

```
SET profiling = 1;
```

Then these steps:

(1) Execute your query.

(2) Find out the query id for profiling:

```
SHOW PROFILES;
```

It will return you something like this:

```
Query_ID |  Duration | Query
---------+-----------+-----------------------
   2     | 0.0006200 | SHOW STATUS
   3     | 0.3600000 | (your query here)
  ...    | ...       | ...
```

Now you know the query id is (3).

(3) Profile the query.

```
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 3;   // example
```

This will return you the details, which might look like this:

```
Status                          | Duration
--------------------------------+-------------------
starting                        | 0.000010
checking query cache for query  | 0.000078
Opening tables                  | 0.000051
System lock                     | 0.000003
Table lock                      | 0.000008
init                            | 0.000036
optimizing                      | 0.000020
statistics                      | 0.000013
preparing                       | 0.000015
Creating tmp table              | 0.000028
executing                       | 0.000602
Copying to tmp table            | 0.000176
Sorting result                  | 0.000043
Sending data                    | 0.080032
end                             | 0.000004
removing tmp table              | 0.000024
end                             | 0.000006
query end                       | 0.000003
freeing items                   | 0.000148
removing tmp table              | 0.000019
closing tables                  | 0.000005
logging slow query              | 0.000003
cleaning up                     | 0.000004
```

In this example, most of the time was actually spend sending the data from the server back to the client.

Comment: I wanted to see for example: SELECT * FROM tables or UPDATE tablle SET column ....

Comment: You can profile that with the inbuild profiler. Just give it a try.

Comment: show profiles show some selects and show status and some set profiling history. but i cannot see my failed update query. i wanted to see on why my update failed.

Comment: That is not what a profiler is for. A profilers task to check what is going on in a SQL statement. You want to debug a failed statement. Please define 'failed': (1) You received an error? (2) No error and no row was updated?

Comment: Query Analyzing to see which part failed. I have series of selects and updates and don't know or why it failed, or what values were passed. I cannot debug properly and fast using PHP.

Comment: Wrong approach. If you're generating broken `UPDATE`- or `SELECT`-statements within a php script, you should debug it with php. One way of doing this: Output your SQL statements (p.e. with `echo` or `var_dump`), and run them from the mysql console. That should make broken parts visible easily.